# How to change column values that meets a given condition while maintaining the values for that column that don't meet the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In my pandas dataframe I have two columns I'm considering **X1** and **Score**. I intend to recalculate and reassign value to values in column **Score** but where there respective **X1** column is less than **500**. The values in **Score** that don't meet this condition should remain as they were.

Currently when I run below code, It correctly changes the values of the **Score** that meets the condition **(**X1** column is less than **500**)** but the values for **Score** that were not recalculated were turned to **NaN** instead of maintaining their original values.

```
def do_not_try_this(df, card, feature, val):
    if df[df[feature]<val][feature].iloc[0] < val:
        current_score = card[feature]['points'].iloc[0]
        print('Current point', current_score)
        min_desired_score = card[feature].min()['points']
        print('Min point', min_desired_score)
        df.iloc[:,21] = (df[df[feature]<val]['scores'] + np.sum([current_score, min_desired_score])).astype(int)
    else:
        df['scores'] = df.iloc[:,21]
    
    return df

# Call Function
df = airtel_base_scores_df.copy(deep=True)
feature = 'X1'
val = 500

df = do_not_try_this(df, card, feature, val)
```

How do I go about solving this?

**NB** df.iloc[:,21] represents the values of column **Score**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need change:

```
df.iloc[:,21] = (df[df[feature]<val]['scores'] + np.sum([current_score, min_desired_score])).astype(int)
```

to:

```
df.iloc[:,21] = ( df['scores'].mask(df[feature]<val, df['scores'] + np.sum([current_score, min_desired_score]))).astype(int)
```

for processing only values matching conditions in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).